# How to make my SELECT query more efficient?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, select

I'm a beginner in SQL and I have some troubles with this request, which just can't be executed because it's too inefficient. Here it is, it just loads for hours (!)

```
SELECT my_db_client_total.email as EMAIL_TOTAL, 
    my_db_client_total.name, my_db_client_total.country 
    FROM my_db_client_total, my_db_client_pro
      WHERE (my_db_client_total.email<>'' ) 
    AND (my_db_client_total.country = '120') 
    AND (my_db_client_total.email IN (SELECT my_db_client_pro.email 
    FROM my_db_client_pro));
```

My tables are organised in this way :

```
Table 1 :        Table 2 :
   email         email
   name          name
   country       country
```

The purpose of the request it to test my database, and to process a further request where I want to select `email`, `name` and `country` from `Table 1` where `table1.email` is not in `table2`.

Sorry for my bad English, and for my level, as I said earlier, I'm a beginner and self-taught.

If anyone can help me or at least enlighten me, I'll be so thankful for your time.

EDIT: I didn't precisely know but I'm working with a table where there is 20 000+ rows.

Comment: up vote for a well presented question appreciation

Comment: Do you have any indexes on my_db_client_total? If not then you should create one on country at least and possibly (country, email, name).

Comment: @Strawberry I can't see the typo?

Comment: Maxime, you really should also look into adding `index`es on to your SQL table structure, so that you can index columns as that will make your queries run much faster with minimum actual code changes. Read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql-indexes.html

Comment: hah, I went away and then came back to the page and immediately saw it before reading your comment. @Strawberry

Comment: Should we edit and replace the table name? I'm unsure of the etiquette but I think that `my_db_client_pro` should be replaced back into the SQL as originally posted. @Strawberry

Comment: @Martin Me too. Whatever you think's best!

Comment: I think the biggest problem was your cross join which appears redundant anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your query (fixed up a bit with table aliases):

```
SELECT ct.email as EMAIL_TOTAL, ct.name, ct.country
FROM my_db_client_total ct 
WHERE (ct.email <> '' ) AND
      (ct.country = 120) AND 
      (ct.email IN (SELECT my_db_client_pro.email FROM my_db_client_pro));
```

(I am assuming that `120` is really an integer.)

In older versions of MySQL, `exists` is more efficient than `in`, so rewrite the query as:

```
SELECT ct.email as EMAIL_TOTAL, ct.name, ct.country
FROM my_db_client_total ct 
WHERE (ct.email <> '' ) AND
      (ct.country = 120) AND 
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM my_db_client_pro cp WHERE cp.email = ct.email);
```

Next, consider indexes.  For this query, good indexes are:

```
create index idx_my_db_client_total_2 on my_db_client_total(country, email, name);

create index idx_my_db_client_pro_email on my_db_client_pro(email);
```

Comment: Getting the error :

create index idx_my_db_total_2 on my_db_total(country, email, name);

MySQL said: Documentation
#1170 - BLOB/TEXT column 'country' used in key specification without a key length 
My field are tinytext...

Comment: @MaximeRogissart . . . `BLOB/TEXT` don't really seem appropriate for any of those columns (`varchar()` seems quite sufficient).  However, you can try the index without the offending columns or use a key length.

Answer (score 1):

Your question states you are using MySQL, so this will give you an inner (record must exist in both tables) join.

```
SELECT my_db_client_total.email as EMAIL_TOTAL, my_db_client_total.name, my_db_client_total.country 
FROM my_db_client_total inner join my_db_client_pro on my_db_client_pro.email = my_db_client_total.email
WHERE (my_db_client_total.email<>'' ) AND (my_db_client_total.country = '120');
```

To select a row that does not exist in the other table do this:

```
SELECT my_db_client_total.email as EMAIL_TOTAL, my_db_client_total.name, my_db_client_total.country 
FROM my_db_client_total LEFT OUTER JOIN my_db_client_pro on my_db_client_pro.email = my_db_client_total.email
WHERE (my_db_client_total.email<>'' ) AND (my_db_client_total.country = '120') AND my_db_client_pro.email IS NULL;
```

Comment: THank you very much !
How can i transform this for my final purpose, wich is the exact opposite of the request ?
Can i just change `join my_db_client_pro on my_db_client_pro.email = my_db_client_total.email ` to 
`join my_db_client_pro on my_db_client_pro.email != my_db_client_total.email `

Comment: @MaximeRogissart, no that wouldnt work - I updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT my_db_client_total.email as EMAIL_TOTAL, 
  my_db_client_total.name, my_db_client_total.country 
FROM 
  my_db_client_total, 
WHERE (my_db_client_total.email <> '') 
AND (my_db_client_total.country = '120') 
AND (my_db_client_total.email not IN (SELECT my_db_client_pro.email
  FROM my_db_client_pro));
```

Basically get all the data from table and on where condition getting the email address not in table 2

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a `Join`.

Check them out here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191472(v=sql.105).aspx

Example code:

```
SELECT my_db_client_total.email as EMAIL_TOTAL, my_db_client_total.name, my_db_client_total.country
FROM my_db_client_total AS ct
    CROSS JOIN my_db_client_pro AS cp
    ON ct.CLIENT_ID = cp.CLIENT_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

If you join the 2 tables, why don't you use the right side table in your query instead of making a subquery on it?

Try this (only the join) :

```
SELECT my_db_client_total.email as EMAIL_TOTAL, my_db_client_total.name, my_db_client_total.country 
  FROM my_db_client_total, my_db_client_pro
 WHERE my_db_client_total.email <> ''
   AND my_db_client_total.country = '120'
   AND my_db_client_total.email = my_db_client_pro.email;
```

or this (only the subquery) :

```
SELECT my_db_client_total.email as EMAIL_TOTAL, my_db_client_total.name, my_db_client_total.country 
  FROM my_db_client_total
 WHERE my_db_client_total.email <> ''
   AND my_db_client_total.country = '120' 
   AND my_db_client_total.email IN (SELECT my_db_client_pro.email FROM my_db_client_pro);
```